# Xindex: Distinguish between differently formatted entries

Tags: indexing, xindex

I am playing around with `xindex`and I'm trying to do this some things which I could do with `xindy`.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index{\textsc{Test}}\textsc{Test} \index{\emph{Test}}\emph{Test} \index{Test}Test

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

At the moment, `\textsc{Test}` and `\emph{Test}` are sorted as different entries under 'Symbols'. What I want to achieve is to have them all sorted under 'T', but as different entries. So I want to be able to distinguish between different instances of 'Test'. With `xindy`, I was able to do this. I am sure that this can also be done with some `Lua` magic, but I have no idea how.

**EDIT**

Further explanation: `xindy`does not like the @-divider which `makeindex` uses for this kind of sorting. Instead it offers powerful replacements functions. With `xindy` I achieved what I wanted with the following code:

```
(merge-rule "\\textsc\{(.*)\}" "\1~b2" :eregexp :again)
(merge-rule "\\emph  \{(.*)\}" "\1~b1" :eregexp :again)
```

I could go the traditional @-route with `xindex` but I would prefer something along the lines of `xindy`. I think it's more elegant and offers much more possibilities (I use `xindy`s regex replacements also for other stuff).

As I said, I am sure this can be done with `Lua`, I just have no idea how.

**EDIT2**

I am also interested in things like having titles such «The War of the Worlds» automatically sorted under W instead of T (I know this can also be done with @, but with general rules, it gets a lot easier). So maybe I should have phrased the question more generally: How can you use regex to do replacement in `xindex`.

Comment: Did you use `@` in `xindy`? That still works: `\index{Test-sc@\textsc{Test}}\textsc{Test} \index{Test-em@\emph{Test}}\emph{Test} \index{Test}Test`

Comment: @moewe See my addition to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there i a supported interface for this, but given that the configuration file is just a Lua script which is executed after all functions are defined and almost everything is accessed though global names, you can overwrite the sortstring generation:

Create a file `xindex-sort-pattern.lua` with the content (This is mostly a copy of the original `index-cfg.lua` with two additional Lua functions):

```lua
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--         FILE:  xindex-sort-pattern.lua
--  DESCRIPTION:  modified configuration file for xindex.lua
-- REQUIREMENTS:  
--       AUTHOR:  Herbert Voß and Marcel Krüger
--      LICENSE:  LPPL1.3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

itemPageDelimiter = ","     -- Hello, 14
compressPages     = true    -- something like 12--15, instead of 12,13,14,15. the |( ... |) syntax is still valid
fCompress     = true    -- 3f -> page 3, 4 and 3ff -> page 3, 4, 5
minCompress       = 3       -- 14--17 or 
rangeSymbol       = "--"
numericPage       = true    -- for non numerical pagenumbers, like "VI-17"
sublabels         = {"", "-\\,", "--\\,", "---\\,"} -- for the (sub(sub(sub-items  first one is for item
pageNoPrefixDel   = ""     -- a delimiter for page numbers like "VI-17"  -- not used !!!
indexOpening      = ""     -- commands after \begin{theindex}
idxnewletter      = "\\textbf"  -- Only valid if -n is not set

local patt do
  local l = lpeg or require'lpeg'
  local special = l.S'@!|'
  local atfield = l.Cg('@' * (1-special)^0 * l.Cc'') 
  patt = l.Cs(l.Cg(' ' * l.Cc'')^-1 * (atfield + 1)^0)
end
local cache = setmetatable({}, {__index = function(t, entry)
    local value = patt:match(entry)
    -- >> Insert your replacement here
      value = value:gsub("\\textsc%s*{(.*)}", "%1~b2")
      value = value:gsub("\\emph%s*{(.*)}", "%1~b1")
    -- >> End of replacements
    if getCharType(utf.sub(value, 1, 1)) == 0 then
      value = ' ' .. value
    end
    t[entry] = value
    return value
  end,
})
function getSortString(Entry)
  return cache[Entry]
end
-- Update sortChar to refer to the first character of the modified sortChar and not the first original char
function SORTendhook(list)
  for i=1,#list do
    local entry = list[i]
    entry.sortChar = utf.sub(entry.SortKey, 1, 1)
  end
  return list
end

--[[
    Each character's position in this array-like table determines its 'priority'.
    Several characters in the same slot have the same 'priority'.
]]
alphabet_lower = { --   for sorting
    { ' ' },  -- only for internal tests
    { 'a', 'á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'å', 'æ', },
    { 'b' },
    { 'c', 'ç' },
    { 'd' },
    { 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê' },
    { 'f' },
    { 'g' },
    { 'h' },
    { 'i', 'í', 'ì', 'î', 'ï' },
    { 'j' },
    { 'k' },
    { 'l' },
    { 'm' },
    { 'n', 'ñ' },
    { 'o', 'ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô', 'ø', 'œ', 'ø'},
    { 'p' },
    { 'q' },
    { 'r' },
    { 's', 'š', 'ß' },
    { 't' },
    { 'u', 'ú', 'ù', 'ü' , 'û'},
    { 'v' },
    { 'w' },
    { 'x' },
    { 'y', 'ý', 'ÿ' },
    { 'z', 'ž' }
}
alphabet_upper = { -- for sorting
    { ' ' },
    { 'A', 'Á', 'À', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Â' },
    { 'B' },
    { 'C', 'Ç' },
    { 'D' },
    { 'E', 'È', 'É', 'Ë', 'Ê' },
    { 'F' },
    { 'G' },
    { 'H' },
    { 'I', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î' },
    { 'J' },
    { 'K' },
    { 'L' },
    { 'M' },
    { 'N', 'Ñ' },
    { 'O', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ø','Œ', 'Ø', 'Ô'},
    { 'P' },
    { 'Q' },
    { 'R' },
    { 'S', 'Š' },
    { 'T' },
    { 'U', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Ü', 'Û' },
    { 'V' },
    { 'W' },
    { 'X' },
    { 'Y', 'Ý', 'Ÿ' },
    { 'Z', 'Ž' }
}
```

Here we use [Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1). They are not the same as regular expresions but quite similar. If you need more powerful replacements, you can probably use LPEG or any other Lua code.

Then you only need to call `xindex` with the `-c sort-pattern` option to use the new config. If you use imakeindex to call xindex automatically, you can use an argument to `\makeindex` to pass the option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}

\makeindex[options=-c sort-pattern]

\begin{document}

\index{\textsc{Test}}\textsc{Test} \index{\emph{Test}}\emph{Test} \index{Test}Test

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. With this I can do all I did with `xindy`.

Comment: A follow-up on this: Is it possible to define a sort rule which will exclude the respective entry completely from the index, in other words prevent it from being written to the .ind file?

Comment: @Simifilm In `SORTendhook`, you get a table passed and you can just delete entries there (e.g. using `table.remove(list, i)`, but you have to be a careful when modifying a table while iterating over it. Especially you have to reevaluate entry `i` because it might now be a different entry after the old entry `i` is removed and at the end some entries might no longer exists (because the list got shorter after the length was queried)